# cannot import google calendar api library to PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to authenticate to google calendar using PowerShell. To do that, I have to install the "Google.Apis.Calendar.v3". And to do that I have to install the nuget package source. So I start with nuget.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> register-PackageSource -Name MyNuGet -Location https://www.nuget.org/api/v2 -ProviderName NuGet

Name                             ProviderName     IsTrusted  Location                                                        
----                             ------------     ---------  --------                                                        
MyNuGet                          NuGet            False      https://www.nuget.org/api/v2
```

Then I install "Google.Apis.Calendar.v3" and get an error that there's a dependency loop.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Install-Package Google.Apis.Calendar.v3
Install-Package : Dependency loop detected for package 'Google.Apis.Calendar.v3'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Google.Apis.Calendar.v3
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : Deadlock detected: (Google.Apis.Calendar.v3:String) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DependencyLoopDetected,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPackage
```

So I add the -SkipDependencies option and the package gets installed.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Install-Package Google.Apis.Calendar.v3 -SkipDependencies

Name                           Version          Source           Summary                                                     
----                           -------          ------           -------                                                     
Google.Apis.Calendar.v3        1.59.0.2759      MyNuGet          Google APIs Client Library for working with Calendar v3....
```

I then try to authenticate with google calendar but get a message that the assembly is not loaded.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $credential = New-Object Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.ServiceAccountCredential
(
    [Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.ServiceAccountCredential]::FromJsonFile("C:\Users\Windows\Desktop\calendar-346619-92e3766da662.json")
)
New-Object : Cannot find type [Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.ServiceAccountCredential]: verify that the assembly containing this 
type is loaded.
At line:1 char:15
+ ... redential = New-Object Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.ServiceAccountCredenti ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidType: (:) [New-Object], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
 
Unable to find type [Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.ServiceAccountCredential].
At line:3 char:5
+     [Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.ServiceAccountCredential]::FromJsonFile( ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Google.Apis.Aut...countCredential:TypeName) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound
```

So I search for "google.apis.calendar.v3.dll" on my computer, find the .dll and try to load it but I get an error again.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\PackageManagement\NuGet\Packages\Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.1.59.0.2759\lib\net45\Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.dll"
Add-Type : Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\PackageManagement\NuGet\Packages\Goo ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-Type], ReflectionTypeLoadException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand
```

I'm using Windows 10 and PowerShell version 5.1.19041.2364
How can I import this API library to PowerShell so I can authenticate to google calendar?

Comment: @aristov: Haye you tried https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSGSuite/ ?

Comment: it requires G-Suite which I don't have

Comment: Have you installed the depencies as described here?
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Calendar.v3#dependencies-body-tab

Comment: yes, the dependencies have been installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, I got really angry that it was so difficult to install the packages, so this ought to fix that problem:

```
#requires -Modules @{ModuleName = 'PackageManagement'; ModuleVersion = '1.4.8.1'}

function Install-PackageRecursive
{
    <#
        .EXAMPLE
        Install-PackageRecursive Google.Apis.Calendar.v3
    #>

    [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)]
        [string]$Name,

        [ValidateSet('CurrentUser', 'AllUsers')]
        [string]$Scope = 'CurrentUser',

        [SupportsWildcards()]
        [string[]]$Exclude = ('NETStandard.Library', 'Microsoft.*', 'System.*'),

        [switch]$Force,

        [Parameter(DontShow)]
        $Packages
    )

    begin
    {
        if (-not $Packages)
        {
            $Packages = @{}
            $InstalledPackages = Get-Package
            $InstalledPackages | ForEach-Object {
                $Key = $_.CanonicalId -replace '#.*'
                $Packages[$Key] = $_
            }
            $PSBoundParameters.Packages = $Packages
        }
    }

    process
    {
        [void]$PSBoundParameters.Remove('Name')

        $Name, $Version = $Name -replace '^nuget:' -split '/'
        $Params = @{Name = $Name}
        if ($Version)
        {
            $Params.RequiredVersion = $Version
        }

        if ($Exclude | Where-Object {$Name -like $_})
        {
            Write-Verbose "Excluded: $Name"
            return
        }

        $Key = "nuget:$Name/$($Params.Version)"
        $Package = $Packages[$Key]
        if (-not $Package)
        {
            $Package = Get-Package @Params -ErrorAction Ignore
        }
        if (-not $Package)
        {
            $Package = Find-Package @Params
        }
        $Key = $Package.CanonicalId -replace '#.*'   # in case it's different
        $Packages[$Key] = $Package


        # e.g. nuget:Google.Apis/1.59.0
        if ($Package.Dependencies)
        {
            Write-Verbose "Installing dependencies for: $Key" -Verbose
            $Package.Dependencies |
                Sort-Object -Unique |
                Install-PackageRecursive @PSBoundParameters
        }


        if ($Package.Status -eq 'Installed')
        {
            Write-Verbose "Already installed: $Key" -Verbose
            return
        }


        Write-Verbose "Installing: $Key" -Verbose
        $null = Install-Package @Params -Scope $Scope -SkipDependencies -Force:$Force
        if ($?)
        {
            $Package = Get-Package @Params
            Write-Verbose "Installed $Key to '$(Split-Path $Package.Source)'." -Verbose
            $Packages[$Key] = $Package
            $Package
        }
    }
}
```

After getting that done, I found that all packages have to be imported before you can use any:

```
[ValidateSet('net45', 'netstandard1.3', 'netstandard2.0')]$Framework = 'net45'

$ImportOrder = (
    'Newtonsoft.Json',
    'Google.Apis.Core',
    'Google.Apis',
    'Google.Apis.Auth',
    'Google.Apis.Calendar.v3'
)
$Packages = $ImportOrder | ForEach-Object {Get-Package $_}
$Packages | ForEach-Object {
    $Folder = $_.Source |
        Split-Path |
        Join-Path -ChildPath lib |
        Join-Path -ChildPath $Framework
    $Path = Join-Path $Folder "$($_.Name).dll"
    Add-Type -Path $Path
}
```

Then it's showtime:

```
> [Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.CalendarService]::new

OverloadDefinitions
-------------------
Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.CalendarService new()
Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.CalendarService new(Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService+Initializer initializer)
```

Comment: The function that installs the prerequisites worked like a charm. When running the second command though, the one that imports the packages, I get the same error 4 times: "Add-Type : Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.". I assumed it's an issue with .net framework version so I checked which version Windows 10 comes with and it's version 4.8. I tried installing .net framework version 4.5 but it detects that a newer version is already installed and cancels the installer.

Comment: You won't need to install a framework - the 4.8 runtime is backward-compatible with projects targeting 4.5.

Comment: I missed out on the import order and needing to import NewtonSoft.Json. Sorry. Import snippet updated. Tested in a fresh PSv5 session, works without error.

Comment: Working just fine now. I will accept this as the correct answer, thank you very much. When I try to create a new-object using "New-Object Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleCredential" I get an error "New-Object : A constructor was not found. Cannot find an appropriate constructor for type 
Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleCredential.". I'm guessing I'm missing something here also. If you can help with that it would be great, otherwise I'll open a new question. Thanks again.

Comment: It is a new question, and I could go into a bunch of detail about how to explore APIs with PS and ILSpy, but to be concise: there is no public constructor for that type, but there are a variety of static methods (`FromAccessToken`/`FromComputeCredential`/etc) that you are supposed to use instead. See https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Apis/latest/Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleCredential and search on the page for  `public static GoogleCredential`.